# How to create Subdirectories using Windows Command Line?

Tags: directory

How would I create one directory with four sub-directories? I'm having trouble with this question for a lab I'm doign.

> What commands would you issue to build the following directory
>   structure on the hard drive: Create the directory PROGRAMS in the
>   root. In the PROGRAMS directory create four subdirectories called:
>   Adobe, Email, Graphics and MSOffice. In the first three subdirectories
>   create two user directories called: Personal and Guest. In the
>   MSOffice subdirectory create two subdirectories called: Word and
>   Excel. Include a Tree view drawing or printout of the directory
>   structure.

I know that to create a directory, you'd use

```
mkdir \programs
```

But I'm not sure that's even how you start.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the outermost directory. (`md` and `makedir` are the same thing, and both works on Windows.)

```
md \Programs
```

Now create the next level (repeating for each one):

```
md \Programs\Adobe
```

Now the next level:

```
md \Programs\Adobe\Guest
```

Continue as needed.

Comment: Thanks! But question, what's a tree view? This helped out a lot.

Comment: A tree view is a graphic representation of the structure you create, similar to what you would see in the left pane of Windows Explorer. (For basic information like that, you really should ask your instructor. It's basic terminology you need to complete the assignment; you should clarify that with them.)

Comment: Hmm this doesn't seem to work. seems you shouldn't put `/` before a directory, and you can't make subfolder with `mkdir/md` either

Comment: @Coolguy: What are you talking about? There is no `/` in my post at all, and my post specifically describes creating the levels one-by-one. Have you had your eyes checked recently? Maybe a little hung over after a long Saturday night?  Your downvote is based on information that does not exist in my answer at all (and which is absolutely correct in all aspects, BTW, so you wasted 2 rep because of your inability to read properly).

Comment: oops my bad. sorry mate. don't know why I missread `\‌` as `/`... seems I can't take the downvote back, so if anyone's reading this, this solution DOES work. and upvote if you came across it.